# Render a react element to a hidden area for measurement

Tags: reactjs

Does React provide a standard way to render a component outside of the normal flow?

I would like to render a child element in a hidden area, measure its dimensions, and then use this information to alter what's being returned from the component's `render` method. Trying to use `React.render` throws an error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render stuff offscreen in the normal flow. Do it as part of the app startup and cache the dimensions measured. Then your child components don't have to do it.

Comment: The content of the components (and therefore their dimensions as well) will depend on application state. Is there any way to do so at an arbitrary point in an application's lifecycle?

Comment: You can do the 'double render' technique. Render once with a state of visibility set to 'hidden' for the component, do the measurement in the componentDidMount, and set the state of visibility to 'visible' which will cause a rerender, this time with the right calculated measurements. Its a shame that react doesn't have an onLayout prop like react-native has :)